# Stretching input text to fill the division it is contained in

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML div which contains a label and input text. I want the label to take minimum space and give the remaining space to the text input. In other words, once the label has occupied its space, I want the text input to stretch horizontally to the end of the div it is contained in. Here is the sample code that I am using.

```
<div>
    <label >Some Label</label>  <!--Should take minimum space -->
    <input type="text"/>        <!--Should stretch horizontally to fill up entire div --> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is going to result in a really messy look, and a few studies have shown labels above inputs to be faster for our brains to process and derive meaning from. It might not be worth the time to get this working.

Comment: You may be correct, but I have to pack as much as possible so that the user never really have to scroll the page. If I take label and input on separate lines, I will loose some vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8xEDe/3/)

not the perfect but you can try to implement in that

i found this code

```
<div class="notificationArea">
    <label >Some Label</label>  
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

css here

```
.notificationArea
{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: left;
    text-align:left;
    background: #ccc;
    display: table;
}
.notificationArea label, .notificationArea input {
    display: table-cell
}
.notificationArea input {
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: I had tried this code before posting my question. It works in IE9 but Google Chrome does not stretch the input text. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: Try putting an extra element around the `input` and give that `display: table-cell` instead.